Can't connect to Kernel on fresh install of Spyder through Miniconda due to port use conflicts
Every time I open spyder, the console runs into the same error, returning an error message that ends with 'ZMQError: Address in use (addr='tcp://127.0.0.1:57242')', rendering spyder unusable.
This suggests there might be a conflicting process using port 57242, but when I have checked my system, that port is being used by a python.exe instance from spyder itself. Ending the corresponding task closes spyder, opening spyder again leads to the same error on the console.
I am running a fresh install of miniconda and spyder in a dedicated environment spyder-env placed in the default location within my user folder. I had also tried setting up spyder in new environments in other locations (such as my G: drive) with no change in the issue. I've also tried opening new consoles, restarting the computer, spyder --reset, deactivating and activating the environment, and setting up the python interpreter manually. I have tried updating all relevant packages, such as spyder, python itself, ipython, etc. OS is Windows 11.
I used to run Spyder through the full Anaconda install with no issue, but wanted to downsize to miniconda, so I uninsta
My PYTHONPATH manager contains no paths, which seems odd to me.

How did you install Spyder?

Installed miniconda and then ran conda create -c conda-forge -n spyder-env spyder. Also tried it after uninstalling everything with the "heavy" version conda create -c conda-forge -n spyder-env spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython

With the full Anaconda install you should have Spyder in your base environment already, did you try that? Alternatively did you try creating your env with Spyder from the default conda channel, not conda-forge? Possibly you got a very recent version from conda-forge that contained a bug, whereas the version on the default channel should be stable if slightly less up-to-date.
